# AKS Selenium Grid tests are failing with 500 error code and sessions are in Queue

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

installed selenium grid in AKS for the UI selenium tests which are running thourgh Azure relaese pipelines.

I'm able to execute the visual studio tests from Azure pipelines and tests reaching till selenium hub, and they are going to the Queue and tests are failing with 500 error

`seleniumGrid.imageTag=4.9.0-20230421`

secreenshots :

[image]

**kubernetes selenium hub log :**

09:49:58.324 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "6770111d5fff118e7b070bf8c22be6c5","eventTime": 1683107398323021296,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "10.224.0.18:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "48","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession"}}

09:49:58.324 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "373c53f2d1624f8bad9e50714aacba94","eventTime": 1683107398323273998,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "10.224.0.18:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "48","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession"}}

2110","eventTime": 1683107398323928495,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "10.224.0.18:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "48","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession"}}

**Selenium node chrome log :**

Starting ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c11e8cfe3078709382934e3916914-refs/branch-heads/5615@{#936}) on port 19149

Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

09:20:07.468 INFO [LocalNode.newSession] - Session created by the Node. Id: 685fa1e13fd0ac0341f37e217af46569, Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 112.0.5615.165, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.oYw29I}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:40765}, networkConnectionEnabled: false,

pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: http://localhost:40765, se:cdpVersion: 112.0.5615.165, se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://10.224.0.35:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}

09:20:17.251 INFO [ProxyNodeWebsockets.createWsEndPoint] - Establishing connection to ws://10.224.0.35:7900

09:25:30.467 INFO [LocalNode.stopTimedOutSession] - Session id 685fa1e13fd0ac0341f37e217af46569 timed

out, stopping...

09:25:30.563 INFO [SessionSlot.stop] - Stopping session 685fa1e13fd0ac0341f37e217af46569